# return variable and CTE result in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that should return two integers: study asset store and origin asset store.

I have the study asset store saved as a variable from a query and then use CTE to find out what the origin asset store was. However, I'm getting errors trying to return both integers.

What would be the correct syntax for the query below to get the `i_study_asset_store` and `asset_store_id` back?

```
BEGIN

i_study_asset_store  = (SELECT stud.asset_store_id FROM study.studies as stud WHERE studyid = _study_id::INT);

WITH study_store AS(
    SELECT origin_asset_id
    FROM asset.assets
    WHERE asset_store_id = 23 --study_asset_store
    LIMIT 1
),
origin_asset_store AS(
    SELECT asset_store_id
    FROM asset.assets
    WHERE asset_id IN (SELECT origin_asset_id FROM study_store)

)
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        i_study_asset_store AS study_asset_store
        ,(SELECT asset_store_id FROM origin_asset_store) AS origin_asset_store;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong. It should be

```
RETURN QUERY
   WITH cte1 AS (/* ... */),
        cte2 AS (/* ... */)
   SELECT ...;
```